# Derivative in calculus

Tags: calculus

What is the derivative of

$$ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{88}{d}\right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{44}{d}\right) $$

My answer looks weird, but that is as far as I got.

$$ \frac{-1}{1+\left(\frac{88}{d}\right)^2} \cdot 88d^{-2} + \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{44}{d}\right)^2} \cdot 44d^{-2} $$

Is it right? because I think it is not as what it suppose to be.

Comment: Yes, if you are differentiating with respect to $d$, it is right.  I can guess what the original problem is. Finding where the derivative is $0$ will not be difficult.

Comment: As you can see from the correct answer by @glace, you had done your calculations correctly; you just needed to simplify the resulting expressions into the forms that are expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first term,
$$\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{88}{d} \right)^2}\cdot\underbrace{\left(-\frac{88}{d^2} \right)}_{\text{chain rule}}=-\frac{88}{d^2+88^2}$$
and for the second term,
$$\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{44}{d} \right)^2}\cdot\underbrace{\left(-\frac{44}{d^2} \right)}_{\text{chain rule}}=-\frac{44}{d^2+44^2}$$